# Python Error while importing module from another directory

Tags: python, importerror

I've looked at so many stackoverflow posts but I don't understand why I'm getting this problem

My file system

```
parent_folder
    |folder1
        |module1.py
        |module2.py
        |__init__.py
    |folder2
        |main.py
```

I want to import module1.py and module2.py into main.py.

My __init__.py file has the following

```
__all__=['module1','module2']
```

Here is what I'm trying in main.py

```
from ..folder1 import *
```

But this give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
from ..folder1 import *
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I've been trying to solve this for an hour and nothing is working. Please help.

---

**edit:** I solved this by using absolute path (nothing else was working)

Comment: Has been your parent directory added into PATH? Then you need not mention ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative imports works with respect to your package.
When you run `python main.py` simply it cant find what is current package

considering your path to parent folder is `/path/up/to/parent_folder`

execute

```
python -m parent_folder.folder2.main from /path/up/to
```

OR

set `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` to `/path/up/to/parent_folder`, then change import to following

```
from folder2 import *
```

and execute `python main.py`

**UPDATE**

One of relative imports use case is to consume your `package` from script outside the package. This script usually acts as entry point or executable.

following is an example directory structure

```
myapp
│   entry.py
│
└───package
    │   __init__.py
    │   __init__.pyc
    │
    ├───folder1
    │       module1.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───folder2
            start.py
            __init__.py
```

myapp/entry.py:

```
import sys
from package.folder2 import start

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(start.main())
```

myapp/folder2/start.py:

```
import sys
from ..folder1.module1 import * 
# this is relative import to "package". 
# Use?: It will avoid confusion and conflicts with other packages in your syspath. Improve readability at some extent,

def main():
    print "do something with folder1.module1 imported objects"
```

and `$ python entry.py`

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this in python webapp2. Let me know if it helps.

```
from folder1.module1 import module1 #i did not try * but i hope it will also work.
from folder1.module2 import module2 #i did not try * but i hope it will also work.
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you transfer `folder1` to `folder2` and then try

```
from folder1 import *
```

or maybe if you want keep the folders in that way you can try

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../") # or maybe sys.path.append("..")
from folder1 import *
```

this will add `folder1` to your system path
if you don't want to add to system path try

```
import os
os.chdir("../") #or maybe os.chdir("..")
from folder1 import *
```

I hope this the solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up as a solution:

To make is flexible to called from child folders and parent folder

```
import importlib
import sys
     

class MyClass:
            def __init__(self):
                sys.path.append('../folder1/')
                sys.path.append('../../folder1/')
```

When you need to use a class from an external a module, use something like this:

```
    mod = importlib.import_module('MyExternalModule')
    my_object = getattr(mod, 'MyExternalClass')
```

This is to answer to @noobycoder, but maybe is not the best practice.
The best approach is to create a package for the external module and installed in your python environment.